# React Native Touchable Area too large

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a custom button with an image. But the image is originally extremely large so I have to resize it to fit the screen. However I can't seem to resize the TouchableHighlight that is supposed to make it a button.

As you can see in the picture, the black area is touchable around the image, whereas I only want the image to be touchable.

[Picture of the issue, touchable area larger than image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuCpn.jpg)

So I need to find a way to shrink the touchable to the same size as the image.

This is the code I'm using currently:

```
<TouchableHighlight
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() =>
              navigate('SplashScreen')
            }>
            <Image
              style={styles.button}
              source={require('./Slices/home1/Home102.png')}
            />
          </TouchableHighlight>

touch: {
    // height: 50,
    // width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    // padding: 0,
    // flex: -1,
  },
  button: {
    // flex: 1,
    // padding:0,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
```

I've tried lots of styling options, nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

So this isn't the most elegant solution, but I tried the suggestions and they didn't work. So I just figured out the exact aspect ratio of the image and did this:

```
touch: {
    // height: 50,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').width/2.7,
    // padding: 0,
    // flex: -1,
  },
  button: {
    // flex: 1,
    // padding:0,
    // aspectRatio: 3,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').width/2.7,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
```

And that worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the stylings for the TouchableHighlight. Also resizeMode style is only for the Image component and not valid for TouchableHighlight. You have to know that everything is touchable whats inside a Touchable component. You don't need to style any touchable highlight.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **resizeMode** from styling, and if the image's height is 1/3 the width as far as I've seen from the image you provided, add aspectRatio={3} to the **Image** props.